# Converting Docx to an image(png, bitmap ect) without office installed on the machine

Tags: c#, png, docx

Ok I have been looking for a working answer for this for a while, and I can't quite find what I'm looking for. I need a suggestion for how I would go about converting a Docx file to an image without office being installed(or any other software that would need to be installed) on the machine. The function will be running in the cloud so I need something that will take in a stream, and return a list of streams each representing the pages of the document. I'm working in c#, and any suggestion on free 3rd party library's that would be easy to use would be great. Also any code examples would be awesome as well. 
Thank you

Comment: Impossible as far as I know. You need a renderer for this. You can make another application run on other computer with Office installed converting the file and sending them to your application. You can embed OpenOffice in your application though.

Comment: I highly doubt that this is possible. The only program that fully understands docx files is Microsoft Word. You could handle parts of docx files, but then you'd need to specify what parts you actually needed. Best option: Don't use DOCX files.

Comment: It is an open standard using an open standard (XML) guys. If you want proof, take a .docx and change to .zip. Now open it and see the pretty XML files.

Comment: @Gregory, it being an open-standard changes nothing. Somebody could write another program to render them, but I seriously doubt that anybody has.

Comment: @Winston: I disagree. Open standards open Pandora's box and there is a command line tool already.

Comment: @Gregory, and the same tool (the one you linked) also supports the non-open standard .doc format. The open standard hasn't changed anything. Rendering MS Word files still requires a huge development investment and that's true before and after xmliification

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to pay ... and use a command line tool ... try this: http://www.verydoc.com/doc-to-any/docx-to-image.html

Answer (score -2):

Office 2007 supports new Open XML file formats.

The Open XML file formats are a public standard.

Microsoft provides an SDK for manipulating Open XML file formats from the .NET 3.x Framework.

[How to: Manipulate Office Open XML Formats Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683.aspx)

[Manipulating Word 2007 Files with the Open XML Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb656295.aspx)

Comment: does not answer the question which was how to *render* the files, not how to programmatically access the file format